# Can you build Win 8 apps on Windows 7 with VS 2012?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have the Professional edition of VS 2012 installed on Windows 7.  When I go to start new projects, there are really no new types over VS 2010.  When I tried to follow along with creating a WRL component as at:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj155856.aspx

I get a HRESULT exception upon attempting to install the template.

Simple question: Does this even work on Windows 7?

Comment: Are you sure it's Professional?  I don't think express supports Windows 7, only 8.

Comment: Yes it is professional.  I got it through Dreamspark with academic licensing.  I don't think that matters though.

Comment: About that, what if I'm a student and it won't accept my school as a valid one?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Getting started with Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386.aspx):

"**Windows Store app development is supported only on Windows 8. You can't develop Windows Store apps on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2012.**"

So no, it will not work on Windows 7.

Comment: Are all Win8 apps Windows Store apps? I thought that was only for Windows RT.

Comment: I guess MS has changed from Metro to Windows Store app then?

Comment: I'll leave this open for a day or so and see if anyone else comes in with other information.  Otherwise I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: yes, Metro == Windows Store app.  You can develop WPF, Windows Forms, etc. with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 and deploy those to Windows 8 as **desktop** apps.  The Windows Runtime Component you tried to work with is only relevant for Windows Store apps, so it failed when you tried it on Windows 7.

Comment: From the answer's referenced link: "and you sell them on the Windows Store." I see that all apps are free until the official release of Windows 8. But does anyone know if/how freeware will be distributed via the Microsoft App Store? I hope they (MS) doen't expect authors to pay them a fee.

Comment: @WildaBeast You, me and maybe the rest of the deveoper world is confused. See Dr.Dobb's [Windows 8: The Most Confused OS Launch Ever](http://tinyurl.com/9qh7sr3)

Comment: @Karl developers can offer their app for free on the Windows Store now and after launch (no 'fee' other than the developer account required for any store app). BTW, some apps are charging now that option was made available in early Sept. I believe

Comment: I'm so disappointed that they don't support development on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot develop Windows Store Apps on Windows 7 you need Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012. There is a free version of Visual Studio Called Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8. It lets you make Windows Store Apps. If you Install Visual Studio on Windows 7 it blocks the development of Windows Store Apps. So what I am trying to tell you is you need Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 to Develop Windows Store Apps.

You can download Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 for free:

http://microsoft.com/express

You can also get a Windows 8 Trial for 90 days for free:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx